# My website search query is not working

Tags: php, sql, search, mysqli

On my website I have a file **articles.php** and on it I have a search field. When I enter the information it redirects me to my **search.php** which is correct and in the **URL** I can see it is outputting my result but it's not showing me my results on the **search.php** body.

**The Localhost URL is outputting after I searched "Can you game on Windows visa"**

http://localhost/qaa/search.php?search=Can+you+game+on+widows+vista&submit-search=

> There is nothing on this page, just an empty box *search.php*

---

**Connection**

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "Qaa";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db);
?>
```

---

**articles.php "Where my search bar is located"**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>

<h1>Front Page</h1>
<h2>All articles:</h2>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/article.css">
<div class="article-container">

<form action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
<button type="submit" name="submit-search">Get answers</button>
</form>

<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM article";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);


  if ($queryResults > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "<div class='article-box'>
      <h3>".$row['a_title']."</h3>
      <p>".$row['a_text']."</p>
      <hp>".$row['a_date']."</p>
      <p>".$row['a_author']."</p>
    </div>";
    }
  }
?>
```

---

**Search.php "Where the search information should appear after click on 'Get answers button'"**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/article.css">
<h1>Search Page</h1>

<div class="article-container">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
  $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE a_title LIKE '%$search%' OR a_text 
LIKE '%$search%' OR a_author LIKE '%$search%' OR a_date LIKE '%$search%'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  echo "There are ".$queryResult." results!";

  if($queryResult > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "<div class='article-box'>
      <h3>".$row['a_title']."</h3>
      <p>".$row['a_text']."</p>
      <hp>".$row['a_date']."</p>
      <p>".$row['a_author']."</p>
    </div>";
    }
  }else{
  echo "There are no results matching your search! Contact our support so 
  we can add this or if you have a result, add it, as a result, using the 
  GIVE ANSWER button!";
  }
  }
  ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: you're using `$_GET` then use it as such, not `$_POST`, you already posted the question by adding the url and query string itself, `http://localhost/qaa/search.php?search=Can+you+game+on+widows+vista&submit-search=`

Comment: and since you're using mysqli, why not use prepared statements

Comment: @Ghost that didn't not work,

Comment: @Ghost can you maby give me a quote on my code where you see the problem plz.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$_POST['search']` Which is wrong. Because your search string is submitted in get method. So you must use:-

```
$_GET['search']
```

Please try this.